# Entity framework transferred data in bytes

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, size, byte, transfer

I'm using EF6

this is my class

```
public partial class tbl_Persons
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public byte Age { get; set; }
    }
```

How much (bytes) will be transferred from the server to the client when used this code ?

```
using (var db = new testEntities())
{
    var q = db.tbl_Persons.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ID == 1234).Age;
}
```

Just transferred {(Age)(1 byte)} or transferred all properties {(ID + Name + Age)(10 bytes)} then select Age on client ?

How can I transfer only (Age)(1 byte) ? (I need to transfer minimum data from server)

Comment: BTW the following code `var q = db.tbl_Persons.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ID == 1234).Age;` may throw. You should have written: `var q = db.tbl_Persons.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ID == 1234)?.Age;`

Comment: BTW: storing an age is risky (store a birth date/year). Limiting the age of a person to 128 is risky;

Comment: Thanks. but this is not my real class. it's just for test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression

```
var q = db.tbl_Persons.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ID == 1234).Age;
```

is equivalent of

```
var person = db.tbl_Persons.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ID == 1234);
var age = person.Age;
```

So you first retrieve and materialize a whole object (with all properties) from the database, and then take a single property (`byte` in your case) from the result.

In order to fetch just the property in question, you should use a not so concise, but more efficient `Where` + `Select` + `FirstOrDefault` (no predicate version):

```
var age = db.tbl_Persons.Where(p => p.ID == 1234).Select(p => p.Age).FirstOrDefault();
```

or with query syntax

```
var age = (from p in db.tbl_Persons where p.ID == 1234 select p.Age).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This is best answer for me